# Pass ssh_authorized_key when creating instance using terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

im trying to spin up a host as part of a stage in a Jenkins pipeline. Before we would use Ansible host-add and just pass ssh_username=user and ssh_authorized_key=jenkins-path.pub.
Now using terraform I am trying to use same key/path and I cannot figure it out. I tried boths as tags and variables. NO luck

i have

```
module "ec2" {
source               = "internal source"
instance_count       = 1
ami                  = ""
instance_type        = "t3.medium"
subnet_id            = ""
ssh_authorized_key   = "jenkins-path.pub"
```

}

Comment: This is impossible to tell without seeing what your module source looks like. The `aws_instance` resource will take a `key_name` parameter which will inject the public key that has been uploaded with the `aws_key_pair` resource into the default user of the AMI via cloud-init so it's definitely doable but we don't know if your module supports it because you haven't shared the source. Ideally your questions should include a [mcve] which others can run and see the same behaviours and suggest a fix.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this as easily as in Ansible using terraform (TF) as TF is primary tool for IoC infrastructure management, rather then instance management. There are basically **three options** to use:

- create a script to be executed at instance launch through [userdata](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/user-data.html). The script would setup the `ssh_authorized_key` on the instance.
- use [remote-exec](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/resources/provisioners/remote-exec.html) provisioner with maybe [file](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/resources/provisioners/file.html) provisioner to copy and setup the `ssh_authorized_key` on the instance.
- use [Ansible with TF](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-ansible-with-terraform-for-configuration-management) if you already have experience with it.